# State based routing in React - Redux app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, redux

New to React and coming from Angular JS background. with Angular I have been using UI-Router which is 'state' based and not tied up to a URL / path. How to achieve state based routing in React? most examples I have seen for react-router are path based. if state based routing is possible with react-router, any examples I can refer to?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add some codes.

Comment: What do you call state based routing ? something like conditionnal display of components ? if so just put the conditions within the render method

Comment: State based routing - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/

Comment: They do have a library for react as well, but not very popular in react ecosystem. So wondering if same is possible via react-router